# how to delete a Node in binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

The program is simple do the following step:

- find min value of a binary tree;
- record the min value in a vector;
- delete the node with min value in the tree;
- repeat 1-3 till the tree is empty.

No error is reported when run, but function removeNode is keep `printf("Remove bug1!\n");` I can not find any logical mistake, so I do not understand why this happens. The structure of this function is:

- 'if min=key`,found it,call function removeRootMatch
- else if `min<root->key` and 'left is not NULL`,go left
- else print `bug`

The tree is defined as following, language is c++

```
typedef struct myNode* LPNode;
typedef struct myNode Node;
struct myNode
{
  double key;

  LPNode Left; //left subtree
  LPNode Right; //right subtree
};
```

Main part of program is as following:

- nmax is initialed as 0,
- sortedvector is alloacted a vector with space as large as the total nodes in the tree,
- min is initialed as 99999.
- minValue will return the min value of tree.
- compareDouble(a,b) will return 1 `if a < b`,return 2 `if a > b`,return 3 if equal

  //remove root
      void removeRootMatch(LPNode Root)
      {
          LPNode tmp = MakeNewNode(Root->key);
          tmp->Left = Root->Left;
          tmp->Right = Root->Right;
          //no child
          if(Root->Left==NULL && Root->Right == NULL) {
              Root = NULL;
              delete Root;
          } else if(Root->Left==NULL && Root->Right!=NULL){ //one right child
              Root = Root->Right;
              tmp->Right = NULL;
              delete tmp;
          } else {
              printf("Remove root bug!\n");
          }
      }

  ```
  //remove a node
  void removeMatch(LPNode Root,LPNode match,bool left)
  {
      //no child
      if(match->Left==NULL && match->Right == NULL){
          left==true?
          Root->Left=NULL:
          Root->Right=NULL;
          delete match;
      }
      else if(match->Left==NULL && match->Right!=NULL){//one right child
          left==true?
          Root->Left=match->Right:
          Root->Right=match->Right;
          delete match;
      } else {
          printf("Remove root bug!\n");
      }
  }


  //delete a node
  void removeNode(LPNode Root,double min)
  {
      if(compareDouble(min,Root->key)==3){
          removeRootMatch(Root);
      }else if(compareDouble(min,Root->key)==1 && Root->Left != NULL) {
          compareDouble(min,Root->key)==3 ?
          removeMatch(Root,Root->Left,true):
          removeNode(Root->Left,min);
      }else{
          printf("Remove bug1!\n");
      }
  }
  ```

This is the function call removeNode function.

```
//call minValue to find the min key
//record the min key in a vector
//call removeNode to delete the Node
//repeat till the tree is empty
void problem1(LPNode Root,double* sortedvector,int& nmax)
{
    double min = MAX;
    while(Root!=NULL)
    {
        sortedvector[nmax] = minValue(Root,min) ;
        nmax++;
        removeNode(Root,min);
    }
    printf("The tree is empty");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I saw the title and downvoted. I appreciate you put effort in formatting your question, but god damn this topic has been beaten to death already.

Answer (score 1):

```
sortedvector[nmax] = minValue(Root,min) ;
removeNode(Root,sortedvector[nmax]);//change here
nmax++;
```

you have problem to pass the min. I am here to answer, not just read the title and vote.